# select all checkboxes inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Am having a list of check boxes in ng-repeat as:

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in results">
      <label class="inlinelabel checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[item.id]"><i></i>
      </label>
</div>
```

I would like to select all checkboxes on click of a single check box that is outside the ng-repeat.

```
   <label> Select All </label>
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()">
```

I tried the code in controller but its not working.

```
   $scope.checkAll=()=>{
                if ($scope.selectedAll) {
                    $scope.selectedAll = true;
                } else {
                    $scope.selectedAll = false;
                }
                angular.forEach($scope.employees,function (selected) {
                    selected[selected.id] = $scope.selectedAll;
                });
            }
```

Comment: Use ng-cheked property

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: @MANOJ, do you want to just "select" the checkboxes, or also change the underlying model, because the accepted solution does not change the model bound to each checkbox

Comment: @New Dev.I wanted to change the model ie., get the model value of the selected check box.But I managed to get the values by using the ng-change function

Comment: @MANOJ, you wanted a button to select-all, right? The accepted answer indeed selects all the checkboxes, but their models aren't affected, meaning that they would not all be "true" - which to me means that the answer doesn't answer your problem. correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You are right @New Dev.updated my decision

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other answers here indeed make all the checkboxes "selected", but I think the idea is to make the underlying model also change, which those answers fail to do.

This is because Angular would not change the model when `ng-checked` changes. Instead, the right way to "select all" is to change the models - and the View just follows.

```
<button ng-click="selectAll()">select all</button>
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <label>
    {{item.n}}:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[item.id]">
  </label>
</div>
```

And in the controller, simply set all the items to be `true` in `selected`:

```
$scope.selected = {};
$scope.selectAll = function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
    var item = $scope.items[i];

    $scope.selected[item.id] = true;
  }
};
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0TDoZz4ahWwg5JbzSkce?p=preview)

The ViewModel "drives" the View (with the exception of the bi-directional directives, like `ng-model`, that allows the View to change the ViewModel, typically based on user interaction), so whenever you want to change something, start by asking yourself "how would I want the ViewModel to look like", rather than, how the View should look. The View will follow the ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks @New Dev!!Well Explained

Answer (score 1):

You can use "for in loop" to achieve this

HTML code:

```
 <button ng-click="checkAll()">check all</button>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <p>
      {{item.n}}:
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sel[item.id]">
    </p>
  </div>
```

Controller Code:

```
$scope.items = [
    {id: 123, name: "checkbox1"},
    {id: 234, name: "checkbox2"},
    {id: 456, name: "checkbox3"},
    {id: 567, name: "checkbox4"},
    ];

  $scope.sel = {};
  $scope.checkAll = function()
  {
    for(i in $scope.items)
      $scope.sel[$scope.items[i].id]=true;
  }
```

Please check the working demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LdecfDrJRmE2MoUBkr6f)

Answer (score 0):

Er, is it wrong with the *if* code? It does nothing if you write that. Try below.

```
if (!$scope.selectedAll) {
    $scope.selectedAll = true;
} else {
    $scope.selectedAll = false; 
}
```

Comment: But I need to make ng-model=selected[item.id] to be true

Answer (score 0):

Using the demo by squiroid, You can also do this:
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/jh1svmr0/1/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in results">
        <label class="inlinelabel checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.id" ng-checked="toggle"><i>{{item.name}}</i>

        </label>
    </div>
    <label>Select All</label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="toggle=!toggle">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.toggle = false;
    $scope.results = [{
        'id': '1',
            'name': 'rachit'
    }, {
        'id': '2',
            'name': 'rachit1'
    }, {
        'id': '3',
            'name': 'rachit2'
    }    
    ];
}
```

Comment: Yeah :D I used your fiddle for the demo. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

you can toggle checkbox and get the value like this.By the way use linq.js.

```
<dl ng-controller="selectCtrl">
  <dt>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-change="toggleSelect('all')"/> select all
  </dt>
  <dd ng-repeat="x in list">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="select[$index]" ng-change="toggleSelect()" ng-true-value="{{x.id}}" ng-false-value="" />{{x.name}}
  </dd>
</dl>

var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('selectCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.selectAll    = false;
  $scope.select       = [];
  $scope.toggleSelect = function (tag) {

    if (tag == 'all') {
      if ($scope.selectAll) {
        $scope.select = $.Enumerable.From($scope.list).Select("$.id").ToArray();
      } else {
        $scope.select = []
      }
    } else {
      var items        = $.Enumerable.From($scope.select).Where('$').ToArray();
      $scope.select    = $.Enumerable.From($scope.list).Select(function (x) {
        if (items.indexOf(x.name) > -1) {
          return x.name;
        }
        return '';
      }).ToArray();
      $scope.selectAll = !$.Enumerable.From($scope.select).Any('!$');

    }
  };
  $scope.checkSelect  = function () {
    return $.Enumerable.From($scope.select).Any('$');
  };
  $scope.list         =
    [
      {id: 1, name: "checkbox1"},
      {id: 2, name: "checkbox2"},
      {id: 3, name: "checkbox3"},
      {id: 4, name: "checkbox4"}
    ];

});
```

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use ng-checked

Small working demo :)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in results">
      <label class="inlinelabel checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.id" ng-checked="checkall"><i>{{item.name}}</i>
      </label>
</div>
      <label> Select All </label>
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()">
</div>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.checkall=false;
    $scope.results=[
        {'id':'1','name':'rachit'},
        {'id':'2','name':'rachit1'},
        {'id':'3','name':'rachit2'}    

    ];
$scope.checkAll=function(){
                if ($scope.selectedAll) {
                    $scope.checkall = true;
                } else {
                    $scope.checkall = false;
                }
                 }
}
```

Small demo here:)
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jh1svmr0/)