# Disable/Enable button based on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I'm having a list of check boxes and a main check box which if selected checks all the check boxes .I can also check the individual check boxes.

HTML:

```
<button type="button"  ng-disabled="!selectedAll">Click</button>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" class="checkbox" ng- click="toggle=!toggle">
</div>    

<div ng- repeat="item in items" >
  <input type="checkbox" ng- checked="toggle" ng-model="selectedCheckBox[item.id]"> <i></i>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.toggle = false;
$scope.selectedIntervention = {};
```

I'm able to disable/enable the button by selecting the main check box(outside ng-repeat) by enabling `ng-disabled="!selectedAll"` .But I'm not able to diable the button if I select any check box that is inside ng-repeat.I tried by giving    `ng-model="!selectedCheckBox"` but didn't worked that way.Any possible solution is highly appreciated.Thanks

```
$scope.toggle = false;
$scope.selectedCheckBox = {};
```

Comment: selectedAll == false?

Comment: possible duplicate of [select all checkboxes inside ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002278/select-all-checkboxes-inside-ng-repeat)

Comment: Yes.That is working fine.Problem is with the check box inside ng-repeat.If any selected should make the button disabled

Comment: @New Dev.Its the continuation of that question

Comment: @MANOJ, I just noticed that it was your question actually :) What is the difference between the two?

Comment: to do that you will need a function, which finds out the number of items checked.. if its greathr than zero then disable

Comment: @NewDev The previous question was to check all the check boxes by clicking a single check box .This one is to enable/disable button by clicking any one/more than one  check box inside ng-repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do following

Add

```
ng-click="checked(toggle)"
```

In

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="checked(toggle)" ng-model="selectedCheckBox[item.id]">
```

And change button like this

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="!toggle">Click</button>
```

And in controller

```
 $scope.checked = function () {
     $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;
 }
```