# How to enable/disable button when Checkbox is checked in a table using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

```
<div>    
<table class="table">

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="student in ClassStudents | filter:stdsearch">
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="student.isselected"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div>
 <input type="submit" ng-disabled="!student.isselected" value="Assign"  />
</div>
</div>
```

I want enable button only when check box is checked. But it is not working for me. Please suggest.

Comment: but I dont see any button in your tr

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002278/select-all-checkboxes-inside-ng-repeat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the problem is caused by referencing `student` outside of ng-repeat.

Assuming you have multiple students, and you only want the button to be enabled when at least 1 student is selected, then you'll need to loop over `ClassStudents` and check whether any of them is selected.

```
<button ng-disabled="countChecked() == 0">enable/disable</button>

$scope.countChecked = function(){
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.ClassStudents, function(value){
        if (value.isselected) count++;
    });

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it helped. :)

Comment: I used this but it returns TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null

Comment: There is no 'checked' anywhere in the code, can you make sure all the variable names are correct?

Answer (score 1):

Check the fiddle. It will enable the button when checkbox is checked and disable when checkbox is unchecked.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="student.isSelected"/>
    <button ng-disabled="!student.isSelected" >enable/disable</button>
</div>

//js code

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.student = {isselected: false};
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14629/

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-disabled='student.isselected'` in your button.

[Angular ng-disabled documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Comment: My button at out side of table Sir

Comment: Answered it before your edit was made. I will update the answer